# How to stop test location provider

Tags: android, gps, mocking, location

Currently, I'm developing an application that injects locations into Android. This application  should inject locations at specific moments. Before and after, normal GPS should be used.

My software is able to switch to mock locations and inject locations succesfully. But I am not able to make Android listen to normal GPS again.

My code to set-up:

```
mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
mLocationManager.addTestProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, false, false, false, false, true, true, true, 0, /*magic*/5);
mLocationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, true);
```

My failing attempt to stop:

```
mLocationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(PROVIDER_NAME, false);
mLocationManager.removeTestProvider(PROVIDER_NAME);
```

My question: how to stop provide mock locations and resume default Android GPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out it was due to two reasons.

First, the `setTestProviderEnabled(PROVIDER_NAME, false)` call was not needed. Second, when looking into the Android source code, it showed that the normal GPS will not be activated automatically. By requesting location updates after the `removeTestProvider()` call, the normal GPS signal will be activated and everything works fine.

Comment: So the solution was doing nothing? just not sending a new test location?

Comment: No, it worked again after registering a new location listener. Then the real GPS will again be used for location updates.